# PasswordDeriveBytes.GetBytes(), Algorithm for Multiple Calls

Tags: c#, algorithm, key, concatenation, sha1

I am interested in the algorithm of the PasswordDeriveBytes class for educational purposes which, as far as I'm concerned, uses the old PKBKDF1 function. I have read the algorithm in the following answer-post: [What is the algorithm behind PasswordDeriveBytes?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/22272)

Since it uses the SHA-1 hash algorithm, the maximum generated output of the PKBKDF1 function is 20 bytes, but the `GetBytes()` function implements an extension algorithm in case of larger desired output, which is explained in the question linked above.

I have implemented the algorithm and created a function that has identical output, and has been tested in various different desired output sizes. Essentially meaning that, eg. `PasswordDeriveBytes( ... ).GetBytes(44) == MyPasswordDeriveBytes( ... ).GetBytes(44)`.

As far as I can tell, the answer in the question linked claims that, if the `GetBytes(44)` method were to be called, it would have identical output to the two concatenated byte sequences of the first output of `GetBytes(22)` and the immediate second output of `GetBytes(22)`, respectively. In my implementation, this is not true. Therefore I checked whether this is true in the original implementation, and I have verified in my .NET v4.5 build it is not true either. I also checked the source code in Microsoft's website ([PasswordDeriveBytes.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/passwordderivebytes.cs)), only to see that it is indeed not how the algorithm works in the case of multiple calls to `GetBytes()`. What strikes me odd is that, I have read at least a secondary source claiming the same functionality. Is there something I have missed?

I am asking to be informed about the reason as to why this is the case, as well as for someone to complete and explain that part of the algorithm that seems to be incorrect about the `GetBytes()` method.

Comment: every time I see 'for educational purposes' on questions regarding security I get worried.

Comment: I have been expecting You.